# Summing volumes through a pipeline system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, geometric-network

I need to fill a volume attribute for a pipeline system.  Volume would come from a well at the end and I can easily start with a spatial join to get volume for all the line segments at the edge of the system.

At this point I need to find a way to start summing the volumes through the system so that I know how much volume runs through a segment. Say a well volume 1 and well volume 2 come together. The resulting line needs to have a 3 applied to its volume attribute.

I understand that the best way to do this will probably involve building a geometric network and I have explored this but haven't come up with a good way to automate the summation.  I'd thought about using some of the hydrology toolset but had never worked with it before and don't know where to start.

**Finally solved this using a combination of Attribute Assistant and the Water Utility Network Reporting Toolbar with the Summary Flow Accumulation tool.**

Comment: Do you have any indeterminate flow in your network?

Comment: Kirk,
No, I'be been working with a very simple network with only 5 wells and 9 line segments to work with.  When I solved flow direction the arrows show up just as they are meant to. No indeterminate flow.

Answer (score 1):

Set the volumes as weights and use [FIND UPSTREAM ACCUMULATION](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r0000002z000000)

This trace determine the total cost of all network features that lie upstream of a given point in your network. it requires a weight be defined for the trace and flow direction to be set on the geometric network. - All the features upstream of your flags are displayed, and the total cost of these features is reported in the status bar.

By default, the Find Upstream Accumulation trace task does not use weights. If you do not use weights, the cost reported is the number of edge elements in the result.

if you want to inset the sink junction feature class and cacualte the cost for each junction use [this tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015r000000) (Trace Geometric Network GeoProccesing Tool)

Comment: I knew of this tool, however I need volume attributed to every line segment in the system.  Essentially, I'm left needing to solve the accumulation at every junction then apply the result to the pipeline's attribute table. This would take as long or longer than just adding it all up by hand.

Comment: I've updated the answer and add link to GP tool that can use feature class as input for the calculation

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll have to play with it. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what that volume accomulation cost contribute to the pipe network ?

Comment: I'm not look for cost so much as needing to run calculations on each individual line segment.  The calculation requires pressure volume and line size for the segments.  Previously we had just been taking well volumes and pressures and manually tracking them through the pipeline system.  Summing the volumes then computing our result.  Obviously this is a huge time waste for something that should be relatively easily solved by computers.  (These are customer pipelines and projects never take a month. There isnt the time or information to set up a full PODS database and do all this the right way)

Comment: 1.What is "PODS" ?,2. What is the aim of this calculation of pressure volume for pipe network ? Thanks a lot. Geog

Comment: PODS is one of the industry standard pipeline databases (http://www.pods.org/) We are basically doing a simple velocity calculation one the line segments to understand the flow in that area.

Also, I used that Trace Geometric Network tool and resulting group layer didn't really give me any useful results.  I'm looking into some other options right now. Well, I'm looking at any option at all right now.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you only have access to arcgis, but for future reference I'd like to add [MikeUrban by DHI](http://www.mikebydhi.com/Products/Cities/MIKEURBAN.aspx). It works as a large extension on ArcGIS and requires a Standard license. It can model pipe flow in all and every pipe, wells, pump stations and almost every other feature you can possibly need in a pipe network. It can also model overland flow to a drainage network.

Although it might not be that intuitive for a total beginner, it is a really powerful tool when it comes to modelling pipe networks.